# react-redux store not updating

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

The value in mapStatetoProps shows as  as undefined

Index.js File:

```
static initialAction() {
    return fetchUsers();
}

render() {

    const user = this.props.user;
    console.log(user);

    return (
        <div className="usersWrapper"></div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state. usersR.users.users
});
```

Part of code from UserReducer.js file  :

```
const defaultUserState = {
   users:[],
 }

const userReducer = (state = defaultUserState , action) => {
    switch(action.type){
         case actionType.USER_DATA:
            console.log("update_user_begins",action,action.payload);

            let newState={
                    users: [...state.users, ...action.payload]
                }
            state = {...state,users: newState }          

        break;
    } 

}

console.log(state);
```

Outputs are as follows,

Value of action.payload is:

```
[
    { Name: 'ABC', Age: 10, Address: 'COLOMBO 02' },
    { Name: 'DEF', Age: 11, Address: 'COLOMBO 03' },
    { Name: 'wxy', Age: 45, Address: 'Nugegoda' }
]
```

returned state of UserReducer is:

```
{ users: { users: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

Comment: \** console.log(state); \** ?  When writing code example it must be valid code.

Comment: `user: state. usersR.users.users` - that doesn't look like your state shape at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to not forgott to connect your component to a redux store

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(myComponent)`

or check the path on the mapStateToProps and make sure its a good path,or log out the whole state for checking the good path:

```
 render() {
          const state= this.props.state;
           console.log(state);

        return (
           <div className="usersWrapper">
           </div>
 )
    }


    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        **state: state**

 });
```

Comment: I have connected it to store by connect method.So the issue is not with that.

Comment: Then, just try to log out the whole state and check is there the users

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you forgot to add `return` in to your reducer.

```
const defaultUserState = {
   users:[],
 }

const userReducer = (state = defaultUserState , action) => {
    switch(action.type){
         case actionType.USER_DATA:
            console.log("update_user_begins",action,action.payload);

            let newState={
                    users: [...state.users, ...action.payload]
                }
            return {...state, users: newState } // <= here is return, not assignment.         

        break;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return the newState from reducer and don't mutate the previous state
You can do this

```
const userReducer = (state = defaultUserState , action) => {
switch(action.type){
     case actionType.USER_DATA:
        console.log("update_user_begins",action,action.payload);

        let newState={
                users: [...state.users, ...action.payload]
            }
        return {...state, users: action.payload }          

} 

}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

the case was with how I access the value of UserR.It should be users.users[0].